# Attaching refinery cms to existing rails app version 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I have an existing Rails app of version 3.1.1 and I am planning to add refinery cms to it. I have tried googling about it and have found few solutions.
I have placed following line in the gemfile:

```
gem 'refinerycms', :git => 'git://github.com/resolve/refinerycms.git'
```

On bundle install it is exiting in between giving the following output.

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       refinerycms depends on
>         rails (>= 3.1.3)

rails (3.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

This is telling you that refinery needs at least version 3.1.3, while you're using 3.1.1.  The changes between these two point releases are likely small enough that it should be a painless upgrade process.

1. Check whether you have rails version 3.1.1 specifically specified in your Gemfile and if so change it to `gem "rails", "3.1.3"`.
2. Run `bundle update rails`